# how to expand the rows of an input field while keeping it part of the form

Tags: html, forms

I know there quite a few people that say to get a multi-line input you need to use a textarea, but I can't because then it wouldn't be part of the form. Here is my code.

```html
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" value="type here"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The only HTML form element that's designed to be multi-line is `<textarea>`

```
    <form action="form.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
        Name: <input type="text" name="usrname" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter">
    </form>

    <textarea name="comment" form="myForm"></textarea>
```

The texarea is outside the form, but by adding the ID of the `<form>` it's still a part of the form.

Comment: Ok...but is there any way I can make that work in my form?

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you can't use:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="field1"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter">
</form>
```

Comment: If you put a textarea called field1 in the form its value is not available as $_POST['field1'] ? Something is very wrong there.